# php -f option not working from shell_exec

Tags: php

So when I ssh into my server and run the following command it works as expected, and the script runs as it should (note that I am using the -f option):

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/somefolder/test.php

Expected Output is OK: hello world
```

Now when I run the command without the -f option, it basically shows the contents as an html file (which is expected behavior):

```
/usr/bin/php /home/somefolder/test.php

Expected Output is OK: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So far everything works as expected!!

But now when I try to call these same commands from another php script using shell_exec(), it will not execute the the file. Both with the -f option and without the -f option return the same response.

So with the -f option:

```
$out = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php -f /home/somefolder/test.php");
echo $out;

Output is not ok: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expected Output should be: hello world
```

And without the -f option:

```
$out = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /home/somefolder/test.php");
echo $out;

Expected Output is OK: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So it seems to be ignoring the -f option for some reason.

Any thoughts?

Contents of test.php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: Works like excepted. `-f` is optional if executing a file. Syntax from `man php`: `php [options] [ -f ] file [[--] args...]`

Comment: @wiimm my point is that it does not work as expected when I run it from shell_exec() ... the -f option should force it to parse/execute the file and not just display the contents.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: It could be, but I am not sure what to check... when I run shell_exec("whoami"); it returns the same user that I use from command line. So why does it work from command line, but not from shell_exec? You would think if its the same user, that there should not be an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this took a lot of investigation, but I finally figured it out... there are two parts to this:

**PART 1 - php.ini file**

Your php.ini file contains a line that looks something like this:

```
disable_functions = show_source, system, exec, shell_exec, passthru, popen, proc_open
```

So if you want to use, both exex and shell_exec, you need to remove them from that line, and re-save your php.ini file, so line will look like this now:

```
disable_functions = show_source, system, passthru, popen, proc_open
```

**PART 2 - php-fpm conf file**

If you have modified you php.ini file but shell_exec() is still not working, then you most likely are running php-fpm (as opposed to php-cgi).

This means you also need to modify the php-fpm conf file. Look for a line like this:

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

Then remove the exec and shell_exec from the line, and re-save so it looks like this:

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = passthru,system
```

This post is where I found the instructions on how to locate and modify the conf file:
https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/how-to-enable-exec-in-php-fpm/

The instructions are generally as follows. Note you may need root access to do this:

(1) What php version are you running? For v7.3 you would use "ea-php73"

(2) Conf file is located at:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php-fpm.d/mydomain.com.conf
```

(3) Modify the [disable_functions] line and re-save the conf file.

(4) Restart php-fpm with this command:

```
/scripts/restartsrv_apache_php_fpm
```